# How to debug emails on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I retrieved an API developed under Ruby on Rails. I installed it on my server and everything works perfectly well, except the emails.

I can not send e-mails from my server, and can not find error messages in the logs or any relevant information in the terminal.

The configuration in `config/environments/development.rb` looks like this:

```
# ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options   = { :host => 'domain.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://app.domain.com'

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => '127.0.0.1',
      :port           => '1025',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => Rails.application.secrets.sendgrid_username,
      :password       => Rails.application.secrets.sendgrid_password,
      :domain         => 'domain.com',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

The password reset email is sent like that from authentication_controller:

```
# send email
    UserMailer.password_reset_email(@user, rand).deliver
    head :no_content
```

The UserMailer class looks like that:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def password_reset_email(user, pw_reset_code)
    @user = user
    @pw_reset_code = pw_reset_code
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Password reset on Domain app')
  end

end
```

How to fix the emails or at least debug this situation?

**UPDATE 18.09.2017**

Here is the logged informations when I try to request a new password:

```
Started POST "/generate_pw_reset.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-18 12:17:21 +0200
Processing by AuthenticationController#generate_pw_reset as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"email@gmail.com", "api_key"=>"vvfregregregrege", "authentication"=>{"email"=>"email@gmail.com", "api_key"=>"vvfregregregrege"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.9ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'email@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."email" = 'email@gmail.com' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "password_reset_code" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 1[0m  [["password_reset_code", 9197196061], ["updated_at", "2017-09-18 10:17:21.263062"]]
  [1m[35m (29.7ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered user_mailer/password_reset_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.2ms)

UserMailer#password_reset_email: processed outbound mail in 16.3ms

Sent mail to email@gmail.com (6.2ms)
Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2017 12:17:21 +0200
From: contact@nightspree.com
To: email@gmail.com
Message-ID: <59bf9d314cad2_1ab939f22b96051c153e4@ns3045608.ip-149-202-219.eu.mail>
Subject: Password reset on Nightspree app
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <!-- If you delete this meta tag, Half Life 3 will never be released. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Nightspree</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    /* -------------------------------------
        GLOBAL
    ------------------------------------- */
    * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    * { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    .collapse {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
      width: 100%!important;
      height: 100%;
    }


    /* -------------------------------------
        ELEMENTS
    ------------------------------------- */
    a { color: #2BA6CB;}

    .btn {
      text-decoration:none;
      color: #FFF;
      background-color: #666;
      padding:10px 16px;
      font-weight:bold;
      margin-right:10px;
      text-align:center;
      cursor:pointer;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    p.callout {
      padding:15px;
      background-color:#ECF8FF;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .callout a {
      font-weight:bold;
      color: #2BA6CB;
    }

    table.social {
      /*    padding:15px; */
      background-color: #ebebeb;

    }
    .social .soc-btn {
      padding: 3px 7px;
      font-size:12px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color: #FFF;font-weight:bold;
      display:block;
      text-align:center;
    }
    a.fb { background-color: #3B5998!important; }
    a.tw { background-color: #1daced!important; }
    a.gp { background-color: #DB4A39!important; }
    a.ms { background-color: #000!important; }

    .sidebar .soc-btn {
      display:block;
      width:100%;
    }

    /* -------------------------------------
        HEADER
    ------------------------------------- */
    table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}

    .header.container table td.logo { padding: 15px; }
    .header.container table td.label { padding: 15px; padding-left:0px;}


    /* -------------------------------------
        BODY
    ------------------------------------- */
    table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}


    /* -------------------------------------
        FOOTER
    ------------------------------------- */
    table.footer-wrap { width: 100%;    clear:both!important;
    }
    .footer-wrap .container td.content  p { border-top: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top:15px;}
    .footer-wrap .container td.content p {
      font-size:10px;
      font-weight: bold;

    }


    /* -------------------------------------
        TYPOGRAPHY
    ------------------------------------- */
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000;
    }
    h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small { font-size: 60%; color: #6f6f6f; line-height: 0; text-transform: none; }

    h1 { font-weight:200; font-size: 44px;}
    h2 { font-weight:200; font-size: 37px;}
    h3 { font-weight:500; font-size: 27px;}
    h4 { font-weight:500; font-size: 23px;}
    h5 { font-weight:900; font-size: 17px;}
    h6 { font-weight:900; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#444;}

    .collapse { margin:0!important;}

    p, ul {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height:1.6;
    }
    p.lead { font-size:17px; }
    p.last { margin-bottom:0px;}

    ul li {
      margin-left:5px;
      list-style-position: inside;
    }

    /* -------------------------------------
        SIDEBAR
    ------------------------------------- */
    ul.sidebar {
      background:#ebebeb;
      display:block;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    ul.sidebar li { display: block; margin:0;}
    ul.sidebar li a {
      text-decoration:none;
      color: #666;
      padding:10px 16px;
      /*    font-weight:bold; */
      margin-right:10px;
      /*    text-align:center; */
      cursor:pointer;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
      border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
      display:block;
      margin:0;
    }
    ul.sidebar li a.last { border-bottom-width:0px;}
    ul.sidebar li a h1,ul.sidebar li a h2,ul.sidebar li a h3,ul.sidebar li a h4,ul.sidebar li a h5,ul.sidebar li a h6,ul.sidebar li a p { margin-bottom:0!important;}



    /* ---------------------------------------------------
        RESPONSIVENESS
        Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.
    ------------------------------------------------------ */

    /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
    .container {
      display:block!important;
      max-width:600px!important;
      margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
      clear:both!important;
    }

    /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
    .content {
      padding:15px;
      max-width:600px;
      margin:0 auto;
      display:block;
    }

    /* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
    .content table { width: 100%; }


    /* Odds and ends */
    .column {
      width: 300px;
      float:left;
    }
    .column tr td { padding: 15px; }
    .column-wrap {
      padding:0!important;
      margin:0 auto;
      max-width:600px!important;
    }
    .column table { width:100%;}
    .social .column {
      width: 280px;
      min-width: 279px;
      float:left;
    }

    /* Be sure to place a .clear element after each set of columns, just to be safe */
    .clear { display: block; clear: both; }

    img.qrcode {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------
        PHONE
        For clients that support media queries.
        Nothing fancy.
    -------------------------------------------- */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

      a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

      div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

      table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
      }

    }
  </style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<!-- HEADER -->
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#000000" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="header container" >

      <div class="content">
        <table bgcolor="#000000">
          <tr>
            <td><img alt="Logo accueil" src="http://app.nightspree.com/assets/logo_accueil.png" /></td>
            <td align="right"><h6 class="collapse"></h6></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table><!-- /HEADER -->


<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

      <div class="content">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello,</p>
    <p>You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account (fel.bruno@gmail.com) at Nightspree app.</p>
    <p><a href="nightspree://reset_password?password_reset_code=9197196061&email=fel.bruno@gmail.com">Click here</a> to open the Nightspree app and reset your password.</p>
    <p>Or go to the password reset page within the app and enter the following reset code:</p>
    <p><strong>9197196061</strong></p>
    <p>Thanks for using Nightspree app and have a great day!</p>
    <p>Nightspree team</p>
  </body>
</html>

      </div><!-- /content -->

    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table><!-- /BODY -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<table class="footer-wrap">
  <tr>
    <td class="container">

      <!-- content -->
      <div class="content" width="100%" align="center">
        <hr>
        <br>
        <h5><a href="nightspree://" style="color:#000000;">Nightspree</a></h5>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/nightspree"><img alt="Facebook" height="30" src="http://app.nightspree.com/assets/facebook.png" width="30" /></a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/nightspree"><img alt="Instagram" height="30" src="http://app.nightspree.com/assets/instagram.png" width="30" /></a>
        <a href="http://nightspree.com/"><img alt="Website" height="30" src="http://app.nightspree.com/assets/website.png" width="30" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/nightspree_"><img alt="Twitter" height="30" src="http://app.nightspree.com/assets/twitter.png" width="30" /></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/nightspree"><img alt="Linkedin" height="30" src="http://app.nightspree.com/assets/linkedin.png" width="30" /></a>
      </div><!-- /content -->

    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table><!-- /FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
Completed 204 No Content in 63ms (ActiveRecord: 31.9ms)
```

Comment: Change `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` to `true` to have it show an error if it's failing.

Did you look through https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html#-Configure-ActionMailer-to-Use-SendGrid? Your config doesn't look quite right.

Comment: I tried to enable the option as you suggested to me, unfortunately there is no more information

Comment: usually you don't send emails in development. you use a gem like letter_opener or something similar